# VPN, Loopbacks, Ubuntu Server, And VirtualBox

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, network-manager, vpn

Is it possible to create a VPN server in VirtualBox, and then connect to it from the same machine?

Also, will it actually secure my information if I'm using public wifi?

I'm a novice when it comes to server/VPN configuration, and I at least know that I will need a loopback, but I need a little more direction before I start working on it.

Comment: Also try, http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part one yes it is possible.

Not really, no it will not secure your information using public wifi unless your vpn is using an internet connection that is different from the public wifi. It sounds like you would be connecting to public wifi to provide internet access to your vpn and this will not make your communications secure.

You would have unencrypted communication between the public WIFI and the VPN. Because your virtualbox would be using the same public WIFI to connect to websites. You need to connect to the vpn *over* the public WIFI to provide security.

Ideally, you would want to set up a VPN on a trusted network like your home network for example.

Then, you could use the public WIFI to connect remotely to your VPN server computer that is connected to your home network (at your apartment or house). This would encrypt all traffic on the public WIFI because the public WIFI would not be used to connect to websites, only to the VPN.